# The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable, asdf

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Scenario is:

I have Two Tables.

1. Enrollment
2. EnrollmentSubject.

There is One to Many Relationship between them.

I'm trying to update Enrollment by removing childs in EnrollmentSubject And Adding New Child, I face error below when I context.SaveChanges(); in Entityframework 6.0

`The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted`

Here is my code:

```
public string UpdateEnrollment(EnrollmentDTO enrollDetail)
{
        try
        {


            List<EnrollmentSubjectDTO> subjectsDTO = new List<EnrollmentSubjectDTO>();
            using (SMSEntities em = new SMSEntities())
            {
                Enrollment enroll = (from aa in em.Enrollments.Include("EnrollmentSubjects")
                                     where aa.EnrollmentId == enrollDetail.EnrollmentId
                                     select aa).FirstOrDefault<Enrollment>();
                enroll.Status = enrollDetail.Status;
                enroll.RegNo = enrollDetail.RegNo;
                enroll.PkgId = enrollDetail.PkgId;
                enroll.SectionId = enrollDetail.SectionId;
                enroll.AdmittedDate = enrollDetail.AdmittedDate;
                enroll.StudentId = enrollDetail.StudentId;
                subjectsDTO = enrollDetail.EnrollmentSubjects.ToList<EnrollmentSubjectDTO>();

                List<EnrollmentSubject> enrolllist = enroll.EnrollmentSubjects.ToList<EnrollmentSubject>();
                if (enroll.ClassId != enrollDetail.ClassId && enroll.GroupId != enrollDetail.GroupId)
                {
                    foreach (EnrollmentSubject obj in enrolllist)
                    {
                        enroll.EnrollmentSubjects.Remove(obj);
                    }
                }
                enroll.ClassId = enrollDetail.ClassId;
                enroll.GroupId = enrollDetail.GroupId;
                for (int i = 0; i < subjectsDTO.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (subjectsDTO[i].EnrollmentSubjectId == 0)
                    {
                        enroll.EnrollmentSubjects.Add(new EnrollmentSubject()
                    {
                        Status = subjectsDTO[i].Status,
                        SubjectId = subjectsDTO[i].SubjectId
                    });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enrolllist[i].SubjectId = subjectsDTO[i].SubjectId;
                        enrolllist[i].Status = subjectsDTO[i].Status;
                    }

                }

               // em.Enrollments.Add(enroll);

                em.SaveChanges();
                return "Enrollment Updated";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
}
```

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved......
I was removing it from parent, childs records become Orphans with Parent=null in required relationship in which child cannot exists without parent. but I they were  in the context so I also removed them from context.

```
 if (enroll.ClassId != enrollDetail.ClassId && enroll.GroupId != enrollDetail.GroupId)
                    {
                        foreach (EnrollmentSubject obj in enrolllist)
                        {

                            enroll.EnrollmentSubjects.Remove(obj);
                            em.EnrollmentSubjects.Remove(obj);
                        }
                    }
```